# Issue with spring profile not being picked properties value from server env?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I have configured spring.profiles.active environment variable into websphere server and using variable value into spring config file.
My Config.xml is like

```
<bean id="propertiesUtil" class="common.PropertiesUtil">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:common.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${spring.profiles.active}/env_${spring.profiles.active}_config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

and getting exception while deploying application into WAS is like :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[${spring.profiles.active}/env_${spring.profiles.active}_config.properties] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

pls let me know if i missed anything?

Comment: You do have a `<context:property-placeholder` or `PropertySourcesPlaceHolder` configured?

Comment: No, i have configure in only bean

Comment: Then placeholders won't work. You need to add a placeholder configurere to be able to replace placeholders.

Comment: how and where to add placeholders can you give sample ?

Comment: Read my initial comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, 
It's working, I have fetched value of spring.profiles.active variable from WAS environment and stored into context scope.